# Low Search - Cannot add collection from channels from category group

Tags: categories, channel, low-search, low, category-group

I'm working on an older site that was setup using Low Search. There are two main categories, and I need to add the blog into a collection, so that I can set the overall site search to pull entries from the blog. However, when I go to low search and attempt to set up a collection from the "blog" channel, that channel, and any other within its "blog" category are not available to create a collection.

I've been searching for a while, and can't seem to find the answer to this specific question, however I also don't have much experience with this particular plugin, so I apologize if I'm overlooking something simple.

Can I only create collections from channels within one category group?

This site is running an older version of Low Search, v1.1.0.

Comment: You can do multiple category groups - first step would be to upgrade Low Search - it's now on v3.2.0. Looks like something was added relating to this on v2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *"that channel, and any other within its "blog" category are not available to create a collection"*, but Low Search Collections do not take categories or category groups into account. Collections are made *per channel*, regardless of category, category group, status, etc.

In any case, I recommend upgrading to the latest version.